# Killing thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I defined class A which has a method like this.

```
def func(self):
    while True:
        threading.Timer(0,self.func2, ["0"]).start()
        time.sleep(nseconds)
        threading.Timer(0,self.func2, ["1"]).start()
        time.sleep(nseconds)
```

If I define an instance of a this class in another script and run `func` method of this instance, how can I break while loop and stop these threads correctly? Do I need a ctrl-c signal handler in class A, if yes how? Note: I am also calling a system call by `os.system` function in `func2` method of class A.  Problem is when I run main script file and try to stop  running of these threads, they do not stop.

Comment: look here for example on threads communication http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/27/python-threads-communication-and-stopping/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are myriads of ways to achieve what you want, one of the most straightforward ones would be using [Events](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects)

```
from threading import Event

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # the stop event is initially set to false, use .set() to set it true
        self.stop_event = Event()

    def func(self):
        while not self.stop_event.is_set():
           # your code
```

Meanwhile in some other thread (assuming the object your're talking about is `obj`):

```
obj.stop_event.set()
```

to finish the loop in the next iteration.

Comment: It works, however there is still a little problem. When I press ctrl-c in main script which calls obj.func, first signal goes to threads not to main script's signal handler. Hence I had to press two times to ctrl-c how can I handle this?

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit more tricky but still easy: you have to catch the signal (SIGINT or so) in a handler in the main thread and when that signal occurs (i.e. you pressed ctrl-c) the handler is called. From that handler you do everything necessary to kill the other threads. See [Signal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) or google for python signal threads and you'll find some example codes.